# Can we set parameter width manually, in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to set the report parameter's width manually in SSRS? I could see that the parameters are given the width by SSRS itself, and the XML coding does not have any attributes mentioning its width. I'm wondering is there anything that we can add in to

```
</ReportParameter> </ReportParameter>
```

to set the report parameter's width?

Comment: Not that I've see in SSRS 2005, I'll check when I get to work.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, write your query with `UNION`, for example:

```
SELECT empID, empName from Employees
UNION
Select NULL AS empID, 'ALL' as empName
```

This will solve the small width problem

Answer (score 0):

None that I am aware of.